# Weird display layout of images on first load of my web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to build my web portfolio through GitHub Pages, and everything works as expected when I test it locally. But, when I commit to GitHub and test it, I am getting weird behavior like this:

[image: Weird Behavior 1]

[image: Weird Behavior 2]

But, I also get the correct behavior, especially if I reload the page.

[image: Correct Behavior]

What causes this weird jumping?

```css
.item-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 -24px;
}

.item-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 25px 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 0;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 270px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item .image {
  position: relative;
}

.item .image img {
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.item .hover {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #6abb84;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  behavior: url(css/PIE.htc);
}

.item .hover.active {
  display: block;
}

.item .item-content {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 270px;
  z-index: 400;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.item .item-content h4 {
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/bg_white_border.gif) no-repeat 50% 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'novecentosanswide';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.item .item-content p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 17px;
}


/*contact*/

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.images_holder {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 130px 0 0;
  width: 370px;
}

.images_holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container" class="item-list">
  <li class="item web key">
    <div class="image ">
      <img src="images/dungeon_mobile.png" alt="" />
      <div class="hover">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="#portfolio_1">
          <div class="item-content">
            <h4>Dungeon Mobile</h4>
            <p>2D RPG Mobile Game Currently Under Development</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Website reference: https://panoskikas.github.io/

Repo: https://github.com/PanosKikas/PanosKikas.github.io

Comment: Please share your code (or a link to it), in order to allow people helping you; without that, it would be hard to understand what is causing the issue.

Comment: Since we can't see your code, and we can't run your site to analyse it, there is no way we can tell you what the cause could be. Pictures can help to visualise the issue but they don't allow anyone to diagnose anything. It's like showing a mechanic a picture of the smoke coming out of your car. Sure, they can see the smoke, but without physically examining the car they are unlikely to be able to fix it.

Comment: @ADyson, that is actually a brilliant and accurate example; I'll have to keep it in mind for future reference.

Comment: @secan No, not a link to the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (item 1 where it says **in the question itself**).

Comment: @ADyson, ups, I am sorry; I am pretty new here myself and I have not memorized yet all the rules. Apologies for the confusion I might have created and many thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @secan that's fine, we all have to learn. That's why I mentioned it :-)

Comment: Could you post the link to the repo for the GH Pages site? It's easier that way than manually searching your username on GitHub.

Comment: Never mind; I've suggested an edit.

Comment: It seems to be random. When `Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+R` is pressed (to force reload) random pictures pop up. Javascript issues?

Comment: Yeah when it reloads it's completely random, some pictures load correctly while others crop and appear downwards....

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with CSS, though I might be wrong

Comment: I'm so lost, im trying to debug it 2 hours now and I can't figure it out. Have you experienced anything similar?

Comment: No, I've never experienced *anything* like this

Comment: As far as I can see, your HTML code contains some `<b></b>` tags whose aim is not clear and, in some points, the tag nesting does not seems right (for example, inside the last `<div style="display: none;"></div>`). From the console I can also see that there is an image ('/images/img_pf02.jpg', inside `<div id="portfolio_3"></div>`)  that generates a HTTP 404 status. Finally, all your opening `<b>` tags before "FEATURE" do not have a matching closing one. I suggest you review and clean the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i cleaned my HTML although im still getting the same behavior.

Comment: I've noticed that when i click in the All Works button everything lines up, can i make call to this function via js when the page loads?

Comment: Yes, you can - `document.getElementById('elementID').click()`

Comment: Then post a self-answer to help any future users that come to this question.

Comment: nvm I haven't fixed it. I was just testing the local page

Comment: @PanosKikas, if you check the console, you'll see that the `<li></li>` containing the images have some inline style added to them, which is what is causing the issue (the images not displaying correctly have a `top` attribute set to '135px' instead of '0'). As far as I could undestand that style is added by the "Isotope" library you are using therefore the problem is probably caused by something related to it; you should check the template ('cells-by-row.js'), the initialization and its usage.

Comment: Still haven't figured it out :(

Answer (score 0):

You can click the "All Works" link using Javascript:

```js
document.querySelector('li.active').click()
```

I've tested this in the Chrome Developer Console, and it should work. Just put this into a `script` tag at the end of the `body` element.

```html
<script>
  document.querySelector('li.active').click()
</script>
```

Comment: That's kinda better but i'm still getting some weird behavior

Comment: especially when i ctrl shift + r

Comment: @PanosKikas I see what you mean. I'll try to fix that

Answer (score 0):

So, I've managed to hack my way through it by clicking the All Works button after the page has been completely loaded:

```
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      document.querySelector('li.active').click()
    })
    </script>
```

I'm not fully content with this solution but it's better than before. If someone has a better solution please share it!